# Animating dog walking

Tags: android

I am not sure how to approach this. I am doing an App in which I want to show a dog walking. Where do I start with such animation?

*Do I get a collection of pictures (step by step walk) and I load them quickly?

*Do I get a GIF picture of walking dog and somehow load it on Android?

*Programmatically move pixels ( I hope not!)

*Some other library or solution  I am not aware of?!

Please help me with how something like that gets done so I can start reading in that area

Thank you

Comment: *"I want to show a dog walking"* Too vague. Why not a video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you has the images step by step then use Xml and `AnimationDrawable`

first create animated `xml` inside `drawable` folder file for example

walking_dog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/step1" android:duration="200" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/step2" android:duration="200" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/step3" android:duration="200" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/step4" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

now to the `ImageView` set `android:background="drawable/walking_dog"`

on activity `onCreate` add

```
//walkingdog -> is the imageview id
ImageView walkingDog = ( ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.walkingdog);

//now start walk
AnimationDrawable theDogAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) walkingDog.getBackground();
theDogAnimation.start();
```

results

[image]

Comment: Accepted for being right on answer and with an image illustrating what it look like

Comment: If I may ask you Jack, where do I find such frames of movements on the web? I can't even find the right keyword to google it. Most of the time I find GIFs

Comment: hmm if you have good knowledge with Adobe illustrator you can create your own frames , or download illustrator file for a dog for example then make 3 farms of movement then... boom the dog is walking :)

Comment: Oh so I do a search on "dog illustrator" and I should find files that I can download and generate frames? I have never used illustrator so it will be learning curve :( I wished that there is a website you can download image frames

Comment: yes u have to but trust me its too easy , and about the frames start with any frames u already have when u get the experiences start make ur own dog :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go for a modified version of the first approach: create an image file that contains all frames of the dog-walk animation. Draw your dog on the canvas using Rects like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(dogBitmap, sourceRect, destinRect, null);
```

where `dogBitmap` is the bitmap of the dog animation, `sourceRect` is a Rect object that contains the pixel coordinates of the current animation frame, `destingRect` contains the screen coordinates where you want to draw the dog and the null at the end is for a Paint that you only need if you want to filter the image.
Then just move the sourceRect for every frame.
But be aware that having many (big) image files loaded in an android application may exceed your heap limit since android stores the loaded bitmaps uncompressed.

Another way that is used in animation programs (and goes a bit into the direction of "Programmically move pixels") is using [skeletal animations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation). Using skeletal animations has the advantage that you would only need the model of a dog in a standard pose and could apply the the other poses to the model in every frame using animation-bones. Unfortunately I do not know any android libraries that provide an implementation of this technique. Also, you probably would have to model the animation yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So when you play games and see birds flying across the screen which you have to shoot down, are they done using first approach? Or is there another world I am missing here? Thanks again

Comment: I do not know if they are done this way, but it would be a valid approach. Although I thought you want to draw dogs :)

Comment: +1 for the ellaborated explanation

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a simple 2-D game you're making, just do a sprite animation.

[image]

Take a look at this excellent [tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/) on the subject. It's the approach maddin45 described in the first paragraph of his answer, but the tutorial I'm pointing to explains it much more thoroughly.

But if you're looking for a simpler solution that doesn't bog you down into the implementation details, you may want to use a game engine that does a lot of this work under the covers. [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) is one such engine.

You can download its [examples](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.anddev.andengine.examples) application from Google Play.

Comment: +1 for the good links

Comment: All the links are not available.